# Eclipse, libgdx and Gradle. Cannot get Google play services admob to work

Tags: eclipse, gradle, libgdx

I want to use admob in a Libgdx (1.4.1) project using Eclipse (Indigo).
I have donwload Google play services and Google repositry using the SDK.
I have added the following to my gradle.build file in the Android project:

```
project(":android") {
apply plugin: "android"

configurations { natives }

dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.+'

    {more not listed}
```

This is the output of Gradle task `:android:androidDependencies`:

```
:android:androidDependencies
debug
\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71
     \--- com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0

debugTest
No dependencies

release
\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71
     \--- com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0
```

In the Android project, directory `Gradle dependencies (persisted)` I can see

```
support-v4-20.0.0.aar

play-services-6.1.71.aar
```

However, when I try to create a `protected AdView adview` variable, it does not find the class AdView. When pressing CTRL-Shift-O I get a message `0 imports added`. When I manually import the AdView class it does not find it either.

Could anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I forgot to mention, there is also a warning related to the above: Unknown type of Gradle Dependency was treated as 'jar' entry: D:/Android SDK/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/20.0.0/support-v4-20.0.0.aar

Comment: If your project in Eclipse is a Gradle project, try right-click Gradle -> refresh dependencies.

Comment: Having similar problems, but with Analytics. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same without success, anyone has found a solution for this problem? I would like to get rid of the google play services library (as project) in my eclipse.

Comment: have you tried adding them manually instead of whole? like
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0"